# resizing images to load faster in django

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi everyone i'm working in a blog project in django framework where you can upload images and text. I have 30 images uploaded and the page takes 2234kb for most of its images when loading and all the images are loading at the same time. So when my users hit the page (the post list page) load all the images and its make the page slower. If anyhow i could load, not all the images, but a typically 20 images at a time when they are loading and rest images will be loading when the user scroll the page. is there anything how to do it i'm using html template in django. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called image lazy loading. You can find [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/) a guide about it. It should be fairly easy to implement, if you follow the instructions.

Comment: And i want to load the page dynamically not all the content at the same time ..its like facebook or instagram at first it will load 30 or 40 content after that when you will scroll the page, images or content will be loaded.  How can i do that any guide will be very helpful @KostasLivieratos

Comment: if it's about _all_ of the content and not just images, then you can implement lazy loading in your django method which handles the view response. [That](https://alphacoder.xyz/lazy-loading-with-django-and-jquery/) is possibly a good guide, but you can find tons more with a simple google search, if this doesn't fit your exact needs.

Comment: Is it necessary to use iframe in lazy loading? @KostasLivieratos

Comment: No, definitely not necessary. The link I sent you above (and again [here](https://alphacoder.xyz/lazy-loading-with-django-and-jquery/)) does not mention anything regarding iframe. It's done with pure jQuery etc.

Comment: i'm using the native lazy command.     `<img class="img-fluid" src="{{ post.image.url}}" 
    loading="lazy">` . is it okay?